# How to write a procedure in Mysql with table name passed as parameter

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, cursor, inner-join

I want to write a MySQL procedure. It should take a parameter, which is table name.

I have two tables with similar schema and I want to perform similar operations on them. I should run a select query which is a self join and then load results into cursor and do something based on that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE (table_name CHAR(15) 
BEGIN
//
DECLARE A CURSOR HERE, WRITE AN INNER JOIN QUERY AND LOAD results into cursor
   //
   .......
   .......
   .......

END
```

Now I need to call the Procedure

```
CALL MY_PROCEDURE('First_table');
CALL MY_PROCEDURE('Second_table');
```

My goal is to re-use code here.

Comment: The procedure has to use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` to create the query dynamically by concatenating strings.

Comment: @user9920500 so have you finally found it?